# View Controllers & UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, viewcontroller

I'm new to iOS and xCode programming but i was thrown on to a simple project a few weeks ago that is due in a few weeks.  I have the app working to the clients standards but now I'm starting to refine things and have a question regarding the way I designed it.  I have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller, the view controller has 8 buttons that push to a corresponding view controller with a web view in it and loads the page.  I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way to load the given URL from each button without using 8 different view controllers.

I was thinking something like the buttons are all in the FirstViewController and link out to the SecondViewController that has a web view and then when they are done looking at the information from that URL they can click a "home" button and return to the first page of the app.  Basically I've Frankensteined this thing together just to get something working to meet the deadline and now I get to go learn from the beginning how to make it properly.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using xib or storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Create just one view controller with a web view.

When you segue to that view controller, pass the URL to open depending on which button was pressed, for example, like this:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setNetworkPath:)]) {
        // _networkPathToLoad was set by the button click handler. It's different for each button.
        [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setNetworkPath:)
                                              withObject:_networkPathToLoad];
    }
}
```

Open that URL in the second view controller

Profit!